# What is the use case to have an undefined key vs. a not defined key within an object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm parsing a filename with TypeScript and a regular expression like this:

```
import { Filename } from '../models/filename';

const FILENAME_REGEX = /^(?<slug>.*?)(\.(?<language>[a-z]{2}))?(\.|\-(?<region>[A-Z]{2})\.)(?<extension>[a-z]*)$/i;

export const parseFilename = (filename: string): Filename => {
  const result = FILENAME_REGEX.exec(filename);
  if (result?.groups && result.groups['slug'] && result.groups['extension']) {
    return {
      slug: result.groups['slug'],
      language: result.groups['language'],
      region: result.groups['region'],
      extension: result.groups['extension']
    };
  }

  throw new Error("Filename doesn't match pattern");
};
```

The filename model looks like:

```
export interface Filename {
  slug: string;
  language?: string;
  region?: string;
  extension: string;
}
```

My question is, if the `region` group is undefined for a filename `page.en.md`, I'll get an object returned like ...

```
{
  slug: "page",
  language: "en",
  region: undefined,
  extension: "md"
}
```

.. Is there a clean way without much if and else to get an object like?:

```
{
  slug: "page",
  language: "en",
  extension: "md"
}
```

What is the rationale or use case to have a undefined key and a not-defined key?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I've always avoided this by making sure my code doesn't add the key at all when it's undefined, but javascript itself has a way for a property to exist but have the value undefined vs. not have a value at all. No idea if you can express this with TS but I'm keeping an eye on the answers =)

Comment: There is an observable difference between an object missing a key and one with an `undefined` value for a key (e.g., `prop in obj` will be `false` for the former and `true` for the latter), but [TypeScript doesn't represent it very well](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).  For best results: don't write code that depends on this difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you consider "clean".  If you want to use functional programming and don't mind doing a little bit of type asserting, you can do it like this:

```
return (['slug', 'language', 'region', 'extension'] as const).
  filter(k => typeof result.groups?.[k] !== "undefined").reduce(
    (f, k) => (f[k] = result.groups?.[k]! , f),
    {} as Filename);
```

which has the following output:

```
console.log(parseFilename("foo.html")) 
// {slug: "foo", extension: "html"}
console.log(parseFilename("bar.en.html")) 
// {slug: "bar", language: "en", extension: "html"}
console.log(parseFilename("baz.en-us.html")) 
// {slug: "baz", language: "en", region: "us", extension: "html"}
```

Trading `if`/`else` for `filter` might not be a big win, but maybe it meets your needs?

---

But personally I'd just leave the `undefined` property values in there unless you know for a fact they cause trouble somewhere.  The difference between a missing property and a present-but-`undefined` property is observable (e.g., `prop in obj` is `false` for the former case and `true` for the latter case) but in many ways they're the same (e.g., `obj[prop]` evaluates to `undefined`).  TypeScript [doesn't really distinguish between them very consistently](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195), so it's a struggle even to represent the difference in the language.  So I'd recommend just taking some care not to use `in` or the like when checking optional properties.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQOYFEAeAHXCBAQSijgE9kBvAWAChlkMoB7AVzwGcB+ALhoMmTANoBrCBQFcwUUBgC602fIDcQ5AF8G2+gwahIsRCgBiwADYQQcALYo6jZFwvsMyuSAzqnFuF-Y4DAh+ZxUvHyYoTGBWEFCZT28NCBxIEC5YkA81HX16AHoC5DAAC2AuZGjgnGQAE1YILhAAcjBkAHdWKDFkUGRzaJhWHAYEOJkBgEkAGSwAOWIAWSwAfVQsAHEsAA1kAF5kAoA9AAoeAB4XNwA+ADoAKh4ASlOAHTvzi78AoIgbkRwAC0AC8FNQAEyaZ7PHjvO4AHzeQK+1SyAOIQIAWuCoc8Pq9Lql0pk4gDgWCHs8ACQFYA+fLjDLtPBwKBcCDmKw2ewHZCnGCWax2CA5LzPARc4W8-Y3QROJmTaJcdgWdqHUyzBbLNYbbY7O6pIgCoU8iDPDTAGD85WqsA8O4sDjcZAAMldVSadsdbE4XBELWuGBaCjdHttap9zv9LWJ1lJrQUz3lwk9YHYUBA-IDQZaABpkC0fhhAsF84W0XFy7G0vGsiHkHBKoqwM87hpU4K1dBTr1ZSUKHgIKxrRGwFG-Q7xKGAIT7Q4AInYIDqEEFIAgdQXbeidXYSFOHdT-JgBbEyf7AunfLHE+4U7EChnyALMGeeaPqeomkblSlZueSItHyJgyjYDpkA3CCsDIbpTgXf8RXqRpmjaZBbDgMAEFKZBWTAIwQG3HxNAZehFVYKw7gsVgMFOVl2U5U0RXg4ZWDuUowFsCxt2TIoaCDAQF1YhcCzjDIskEjiuIXXRyMo6jaPojlEPseCACM2UNEB2M47iYSOYpqAE5AFw0qAROQYtS1FEzrAssSE0k3SZLGCYKIgKiaLotllKY1TTLgEEtKBdguB06T9L4ozXHcEyNJBCyrL+QS7ILStshM0L7NrcS4ic6TdCEIA)

Answer (score 0):

One way that comes to my mind is to define only required properties in the object literal, and then, conditionally, add optional properties.

```
export interface Filename {
  slug: string;  
  language?: string;
}

const f: Filename = {
  slug: 'slug'
};

const lang = undefined;
if (lang) { 
 f.language = lang;
}
```

The obvious difference between having a property with value `undefined` and not having the property at all is that in the former case the property is reported by `Object.keys()`